# Javascript onClick function - copy text to input value

Tags: javascript, text, onclick

I need to change the value displayed in a form. For example:

```
<span id="copy" onClick="addValue()">**Text1**</span>
<span id="copy" onClick="addValue()">Text2</span>
```

Based from what I click, I want to move it to the input value like this:

```
<input id="paste" class="text" type="input" name="select" value="**Text1**"/>
```

Function

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">   
    <!--Hide Javascript         
      function addValue(){
         document.getElementById('paste').value = this.innerText;       
     }  
 -->  </script>
```

When I click on **Text1** in value fild I get "undefined" instead of "**Text1**" ...

Comment: Please explain this a little more. I don't know what is moving where, or what is being changed, when, or why.

Comment: Please discuss the research you have done on this before asking the question. Showing code you have tried would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go.

You need to pass the element into your function so you can access it's properties to assign them to your form input.

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <span onclick="copyText(this)" >Text1</span>, <span onclick="copyText(this)" >Text2</span>
    <br>
    <input name="myField"></input>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function copyText(element) {
   document.myForm.myField.value = element.innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use:

```
 function addValue(el) {
     document.getElementById('paste').value = el.innerText || el.textContent || el.outerText;
 }
```

And set the HTML tag like so:

```
 <span id="copy" onClick="addValue(this)">**Text1**</span>
```

Comment: functions called from event handlers defined in HTML attributes do not have access to the element or the event object unless they are explicitly passed to the function.  The HTML would need to be changed to `onclick="addValue.call(this, event)"`.

Comment: No, the brackets are certainly required.  The attribute value for an event handler is the body of a function called in the context of the element and passed an event object parameter named `event`.

Comment: Right. This is a lot simpler now.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.myForm.myField.value = "I'm a different value now!";
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Form and input should have a "name" property, like:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input name="myField" />
```

in the case above.